# Does phantomJs error handlers catch the errors?

Tags: phantomjs

When a phantomJs process throws a page exception, say some resource exception, does the phantomJs process die/hang unless we specifically don't catch the exception with a handler page.onResourceError()? Basically, I want to know if error handlers are just a way to log things when they happen, or they are more like try..catch, where you suppress the exception, and if you don't have them, the error causes phantom to hang or stops execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right: [page.onResourceError](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-error.html), [page.OnError](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html), [phantom.onError](http://phantomjs.org/api/phantom/handler/on-error.html) callbacks don't affect script execution, are indeed for debugging purposes - you don't have to catch them. Subscribing to `page.onError` is strongly advised though to help you debug script.

Also note that syntax errors in PhantomJS scripts are currently (v2.1.1) swallowed by a bug in QTWebkit, therefore you should use some linting software, or editor with syntax/error highlighting or try scripts in PhantomJS 1.9.8 first (which will report any syntax errors).